# How to import dates into MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am using MATLAB R2015b. I am trying to import a excel file full of dates using `xlsread('filename.xls')`. The dates looks like the followings:

```
02/01/1996
03/01/1996
04/01/1996
05/01/1996
08/01/1996
```

then I want use datevec to separate the day month and year. for date = '02/01/1996'(January 2nd 1996), `datevec` gives `Y= 1996, M = 2, D= 1,H=0 MN=0 S=0`. For date '29/12/2000' (Dec 29 2000), datevec gives `Y = 35, M=5 D =23 H=0 MN=0 S=0`.
I tried to change the date format in excel, but it still does not work. Can anyone let me know how can I fix this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `DateVector = datevec(DateString,formatIn)`

As per the [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datevec.html). Set your `formatIn` correct:

```
DateString = {'16/09/2007';'14/05/1996';'29/11/2010'};
formatIn = 'dd/mm/yyyy';
datevec(DateString,formatIn)
```

Since MATLAB is an American program all their defaults are American (hence you're not able to call your `colourbar` as you want to). You just have to select a different date format.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. But is there a way to define the format of the date when I import it? I import the data using [ddata,dnames]=xlsread('filename'), Then I define the date using date=dnames(:,1). Is there a way to tell matlab the format of the date here?

Comment: the way you define `date` there is as a string, which has no format according to MATLAB. When you parse it to other functions such as `datevec` or `datenum` you have to specify the format. Going back to strings using `datestr` also allows you to specify the format.

Comment: Hi Adriaan. Thanks for your answer. It is really helpful.  But I still have some problem here. After I load the data using [ddata,dnames]=xlsread('Filename') and read a date using date=dnames(end,1).  Then I need to do some calculation using this date. However, Matlab cannot recognise the correct format of this date. Can you teach me how to let matlab know the date is dd/mm/yyyy please.

Comment: I just showed you that in my answer, specify a `formatIn`. Read the documentation for all formatting options and more examples.